# dictionary using array java

Tags: java, dictionary

My goal is to implement a dictionary using an array and I have got some problems with it.The methods put and get I don't think are good enough to work but I don't know what to modify.Here is the Dictionary class:

```
public class Dictionary implements IDictionary{
public class ObjectDictionary{
    //public boolean isFull=false;
    public Object key;
    public Object value;

}
private ObjectDictionary[] elems; 
private int nrElem;
public Dictionary(){
    nrElem=0;
    elems=new ObjectDictionary[20];
}
public void resize(){
    ObjectDictionary[] ob = new ObjectDictionary[2*elems.length];
    for(int i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
        ob[i]=elems[i];
    elems=ob;
}
public int size(){
     return nrElem;
 }
public boolean isEmpty(){
    return nrElem==0;
}
public void put(Object k,Object v){
    for (int i=0; i<elems.length;i++){  
        if (elems.length == nrElem){
            resize();
        elems[i].key=k;
        elems[i].value=v;
        //elems[i].isFull=true;

        }
    }
}

public Object get(Object k){
    for(int i=0; i<elems.length;i++)
        if(elems[i].key.equals(k)){
            return elems[i].value;     
        }
    return null;
}
}
```

And this is the main method :

```
public class Start {
public static void main(String[] args){
IDictionary d = new Dictionary();
    d.put("a",1);
    d.put("b", 2);
    for(int i=0;i<d.size();i++){
    System.out.println(d.get("a"));
}
}
}
```

When I compile it only says terminated and I don't know how to fix it.Can anyone help me with an advice? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would you use arrays instead of Lists? Is that a homework?

Comment: "When I compile it only says terminated" OK, so it compiles; what happens when you run it?

Comment: Well, it compiles and runs and says terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the put meethod is to add an element at the end of the array.

In your put method, you used a loop to check if elems.length == nrElem, as nrElem starts with 0, elems.length is 20, the condition will never be fulfilled and hence no key-value pair will ever be added to the array. In another word, the statements in the if block will never be executed.

```
if (elems.length == nrElem){
        resize();
    elems[i].key=k;
    elems[i].value=v;
    //elems[i].isFull=true;
}
```

If I am going to implement this, I will first check if there is enough space in the array to accommodate another element. If not, do the resize(). Then just append the element at the end of the array. Also not to forget to update the nrElem.

```
public void put(Object k, Object v) {
    if (nrElem == elems.length) {
        resize();
    }
    elems[nrElem] = new ObjectDictionary();
    elems[nrElem].key = k;
    elems[nrElem].value = v;
    ++nrElem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not incremented `nrElem` while `put`ting new elements. So `size` is zero.

Comment: Even i incremenred nrElem it gives me terminated again.

Comment: Try printing d.size() before your for loop. What is the answer?

Comment: It gives me the output 0.

Comment: That means you are not incrementing value of nrElem. Debug through and find what exactly is happening.